# Differential Open Chromatin Locations from DNAse-seq data

Tags: sequence

I have DNase-seq data (two SAM files or two BED files) in two different cell lines (no control data in any of the cell line) from ENCODE. I would like to have enriched/significantly differentially open chromatin location. In short comparison between accessible regions between: cell-A/cell-B.

Is there any tool that would do that for me? Suggested/recommended command-line option settings for that tool would also help.

thanks

Comment: maybe this article can be interesting for you:
http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23118738 Madrigal P and Krajewski P (2012) Current bioinformatic approaches to identify DNase I hypersensitive sites and genomic footprints from DNase-seq data. Front. Gene. 3:230. doi: 10.3389/fgene.2012.00230

Answer (score 0):

You could try the "intersectbed" program from BEDTools and using the "-wao" flag to report how much overlap exists between each element across the BED files. You can use the "-f" and "-r" flags in conjunction with the "-wao" flag to restrict the reported overlap to "reciprocal overlap". With the "-f" and "-r" flags set, you specify a reciprocal overlap threshold as a percentage of bases overlapping from file A to file B and from file B to file A for each element. This way you can search for BED elements that are covering mostly the same set of bases over the two files and simply identify those BED elements that don't show high levels of reciprocal overlap to define regions of significant difference.

Bedtools: http://code.google.com/p/bedtools/

The above site includes good documentation and examples, including an excellent downloadable PDF manual. I hope that helps!